# XDocument XML pattern from a string

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

**The situation**

I'm using XDocument to load XML files from a lot of different sources. They all contain pretty much the same type of information, but the XML structure is very different.

This is a simplified example of what I'm doing today for a single source:

```
string path = @"some_file.xml";
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var root = doc.Root;
foreach (var node in root)
{
    User u = new User();

    u.Name = node.Element("User").Element("Information").Attribute("Name").Value;
    u.Description = node.Element("User").Element("Description").Value;
    u.Edited = node.Element("User").Element("Description").Attribute("Edited").Value;
    /* ...and so on. */

    listOfUsers.add(u);
}
```

This works, but I would like to make it more dynamic. As it happens, I already have strings containing exactly where to look for my properties formated like this:

```
"Element:User->Element:Information->Attribute:Name"
"Element:User->Element:Description"
"Element:User->Element:Description->Attribute:Edited"
```

This for example, tells me where in the structure I would find `Name`, `Description` and `Edited` in this particular XML file.

**My question**

Is there any way I can use these string to tell XDocument where to look? In other words, is there any way I can dynamically convert the above strings to this?

```
u.Name = node.Element("User").Element("Information").Attribute("Name").Value;
u.Description = node.Element("User").Element("Description").Value;
u.Edited = node.Element("User").Element("Description").Attribute("Edited").Value;
```

**What I have tried**

I found something called *Reflection*, that seems to do something similar to what I'm trying to do, but I can't figure out how to apply it to my problem above.

Maybe there are other ways as well?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try using [`Expressions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that you also have the option of [`XPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.xpathselectelements%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

So all you need to do is translate your string path from this: (After navigating root)

```
`Element:User->Element:Information->Attribute:Name`
```

to: (skip your root)

```
`/*/User/Information/@Name`
```

Which will then allow you to do like this:

```
var name = document.XPathSelectElement("/Root/User/Information/@Name").Value;
```

If Namespaces pose a problem, you also have the option of agnostic paths, with `local-name()`, e.g.

```
/*[local-name()='Root']/*[local-name()='User']/*[local-name()='Information']/@Name
```

Comment: Very nice! This looks like something I could use, and converting my previous strings into these shouldn't be a problem. Thanks!